# Pokemon oras still locked out of time based events 2 weeks later?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I set back my 3ds' time one hour for daylight savings time over two weeks ago now and I'm still locked out of time based events in oras. All my secret bases and pals say "come back tomorrow" and I can't even send myself free gifts from the special demo. Steven says "come back tomorrow" there too.

Its been over two weeks since daylight savings time started. Why am I still locked out?

Comment: Have you played the game at all between changing the clock and finding yourself locked out?

Comment: I think the day I posted this was the first time I opened AS since then..

Comment: Are you still locked out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The game doesn't check whether the clock changed until you load it

It doesn't matter when you changed the clock, because the game can't tell that the clock is different until you start it up. The time-based events lock out begins once the game detects that the clock is changed, i.e. the first time you start the game after changing the clock.